# Calculating memory and CPU utilization

Tags: linux

I want to know how to calculate CPU and memory utilization of a process using the `/proc/stat` and `/proc/status` files. Can I  calculate the total memory and CPU  a user is using?

Comment: Note that there's no single definition of how much memory a process or a user is using. Some memory is shared between users or backed by disk files, for example the code of loaded executables and shared libraries. So don't be surprised if you end up with several different results (even for a single process).

Comment: not just the code part of the shared libraries, even the data segments of the loaded executables and shared libraries can attribute to the memory consumption, however, it is important to note that how much incremental cost of the memory is being applied/used by the process. Look at `pmap` output of the process id.

Answer (score 1):

`ps` is the simplest interface to the information in `/proc`.

Here's one way to list per user memory:

```
$ ps -e -o uid,vsz | awk '
{ usage[$1] += $2 }
END { for (uid in usage) { print uid, ":", usage[uid] } }'
```

If you really want to use proc, I would suggest using something like Python or Perl to iterate once over `/proc/*/status`, and store the user/usage key/value pair in a hash.

The relevant fields of `/proc/PID/status` appear to be:

```
Uid:    500     500     500     500
VmSize:     1234 kB
```

I think the four Uid numbers are real uid, effective uid, saved uid, and fs uid.

Assuming you want real uid, something like this should work:

```
# print uid and the total memory (including virtual memory) in use by that user
# TODO add error handling, e.g. not Linux, values not in kB, values not ints, etc.

import os
import sys
import glob

# uid=>vsz in KB
usermem = {}

# obtain information from Linux /proc file system
# http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html
os.chdir('/proc')
for file in glob.glob('[0-9]*'):
    with open(os.path.join(file, 'status')) as status:
        uid = None
        mem = None
        for line in status:
            if line.startswith('Uid:'):
                label, ruid, euid, suid, fsuid = line.split()
                uid = int(ruid)
            elif line.startswith('VmSize:'):
                label, value, units = line.split()
                mem = int(value)
        if uid and mem:
            if uid not in usermem:
                usermem[uid] = 0
            usermem[uid] += mem

for uid in usermem:
    print '%d:%d' % (uid,usermem[uid])
```

CPU is much harder.

The ps(1) man page says:

> ```
>    CPU usage is currently expressed as the percentage of time spent
>    running during the entire lifetime of a process. This is not ideal,
>    and it does not conform to the standards that ps otherwise conforms to.
>    CPU usage is unlikely to add up to exactly 100%.
> ```

So I'm not sure.  Maybe look at `top` to see how it handles it.  Or you could run `ps -e -o uid,pid,elapsed` twice at a given interval, and subtract the two times, or something.

Or install something that's better for this purpose, such as [process accounting](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Process-Accounting/pa.html).

Comment: Great one ... never knew `ps` could do these things :)

Comment: thanx a lot.....i ran the script posted by you...it gives me the memory used by a user but when I computed the same thing with a utility named smem the results were different.The command I used was "smem -u" according to the man page of smem it gives me the memory used by the user.I want to know why there is difference in the output generated by the two.I would really be obliged.

Comment: @nishan: The smem home page explains this.  In short: it depends on how you count virtual memory and shared libraries.  Read about vsz versus rss versus pss for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `/proc/meminfo` file:

```
cat /proc/meminfo | head -2
MemTotal:        2026816 kB
MemFree:          377524 kB
```

Using the above two entries you can calculate how much memory is being used at the moment:

```
cat /proc/meminfo | head -2 | awk 'NR == 1 { total = $2 } NR == 2 { free = $2 } END { print total, free, total - free }'
```

Comment: That's not per user.